# PostSharp aspects and mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, postsharp

I add postsharp aspects to my mvc.net app. and start to have this error:

**The custom attribute 'XXXXX.LogAspect' constructor threw the exception InvalidOperationException: Cannot load dynamically generated serialization assembly. In some hosting environments assembly load functionality is restricted, consider using pre-generated serializer. Please see inner exception for more information.**

any help on this?
thanks in advance?